# Computation with a transformation of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

The random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[-4,4]$. Compute $P(X^2 ≤ 9)$.

I tried to define $Y = X^2$ and compute the density of this transformed variable. The PDF of the uniform distribution is $f_x(x) = \frac{1}{8}$. What I got as a transformed density is $f_y(y) = \frac{1}{16\sqrt(y)}$.

However, if I calculate the integral of that transformed density from $0$ to $9$, I get a wrong result. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the uniform can take negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
P(X^2<9)=P(-3<X<3)=\int_{-3}^{3}f(x)\,dx
$$
where $f$ is the [density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution#Probability_density_function) for $X$.

Now what you need is to find the correct density function for $X$ and then integrate it.

---

Notes.

It is fairly easy the see by intuitions of "uniform distribution" that
$$
P(-3<X<3)=\frac{\textrm{length of the interval }[-3,3]}{\textrm{length of the interval}[-4,4]}=\frac34
$$

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there a way to do it through a transformation of the density?

Comment: @Luca in principle yes. But that makes things more complicated than necessary. You do transformation only when things become easier.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I usually don't realize how one can solve the problem in a simple, elegant way, without going through unnecessary maths. But thanks for the very quick response!

Comment: @Luca the first thing to try is simply the definition :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your transformed density should be $f_Y(y) = \dfrac{1}{8\sqrt{y}}$ for $0 \lt y \le 4$.

You may have forgotten to account for two different values of $X$ corresponding to each value of $Y$

You then get $$\int_0^9 f_Y(y) \, dy = \frac34$$